# Application has stopped Android

Tags: java, android

Help me please.[image]

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

Comment: please post the error and code here in the question and not as an image.

Comment: post your complete activity_main.xml code.

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor**.
That's your error. 
Change your activity theme to NoActionBar theme. It'll fix your problem.

```
<style name="NoActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
 ...
</style>
```

Comment: don't forget to put it on manifest too  in tag activity add :
`android:theme="@style/NoActionBarTheme"`